# Load incremental Fact tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, dimensional

My source table would always be a Trucnate and load.
My Dim is SCD2.
MY fact will have an incremental load.

Can you please let me know which would be the ideal approach   for getting the desired result  .

### Day1:

### StgActivity Table:{truncate and Load}

```
ActivityID ProjectID ActivityName ActivityVal  

1          1         TestData1      100
```

### **DimActivity-SCD2**

```
ActivityKey ActivityID ActivityName Active 

100         1          TestData1    1
```

### **FactActivity**

```
ActivityKEy    ActivityValue

100              100
```

### **Day2:**

### **StgActivity Table:{truncate and Load}**

```
ActivityID ProjectID ActivityName ActivityVal  

1          1         TestData2      100
```

### **DimActivity-SCD2**

```
ActivityKey ActivityID ActivityName Active 

100         1          TestData1     0
101         1          TestData2     1
```

### **FactActivity**

```
ActivityKEy    ActivityValue

100             100
101             100
```

### **Day3:**

### **StgActivity Table:{truncate and Load}**

```
ActivityID ProjectID ActivityName ActivityVal  

1          1         TestData1      105
```

### **DimActivity-SCD2**

```
ActivityKey ActivityID ActivityName Active 

100         1          TestData1     0
101         1          TestData2     1
```

### **FactActivity**

```
ActivityKEy    ActivityValue

100              100
101              105
```

Comment: What is the software with which you are working? I have no clue what you want to do..

Comment: Using SQL server i have to update fact tables/